# How to change the order of received UDP messages for testing

Tags: udp, integration

I have a requirement that a client sends UDP packets to a server, and the server needs to tolerant the interleaved order of the UDP packets. IE, the UDP packets sent order of P1, P2 may be handled in order P2, P1 and the correctness shall be sure.

Now the question is testing. How do I test this out-of-order scenario when I am integrating the client and server?

For unit testing of client or server, I can emulate any order no problem. But when do integration test, I think I need some tool which can change the order of the UDP packets but I don't find a tool which claims to be capable of doing this so far.

Comment: On Linux, you could try using tc - more info at http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Packet_re-ordering

Comment: @venkatc Looks great. Thank you! Btw do you know whether there is similar thing for Windows? My app is target to both os

Comment: google suggest https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/ could do the job - check,if it works for you